# A slot for multiple buttons

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have two browse buttons in my application.
I need to execute the function `browseButtonClickHandler()` for both the two buttons.
but the problem is, how can I identify which button is clicked?
I need to paste the browsed folder to a text field.
create the signal and slot through the ui editor.
I have assigned the function for both and its working too.
But only difficulty is to identify the button.
please help me.

Comment: A trivial solution would be to use two more slot functions: `browseButton1ClickHandler(){ button1Clicked(); browseButtonClickHandler();}`. However, my qt skills are quite bad, so I would have to read the docs to get a better solution.

Comment: If it need to create two more slots, then its better to create two separate slots for that two buttons. I need to simplify it to a single functions. that's why I asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QObject * QObject::sender ()` to know from where the signal originates.

You can also look into `QSignalMapper`. In the document, they have mentioned an example same as your problem

http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qsignalmapper.html#details

Comment: wow!
it worked for me...
`QObject *sender =  QObject::sender ();
QMessageBox::information(0, "Button", sender->objectName());`
got the button name..
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Use QButtonGroup. Maybe this link could help.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#id

Comment: this is the cleaner way to go. Elaborate a bit more?

Comment: yes, it is. select those buttons->right click->assign to a new group button. then connect buttonclicked() signals to a slot e.g  connect(ui->commandtype,SIGNAL(buttonClicked(int)),this,SLOT(currentType_response(int)));. done! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a subclass of button class which has an index field and a virtual function that gives this index value.
I assume that in `browseButtonClickHandler()` you get a pointer to the button, so cast it to your button subclass and get the index value.

Comment: Sorry, that's not clear for me because I'm not a qt expert. I'm just a beginner. what you mean by subclass and please tell me how the function gets the pointer to the button?

Comment: you create a class which is inherited from `QButton`, add a private variable (e.g. `int buttonIndex`), create a constructor which has an int parameter in addition others you want. When you create the button, you have to specify the index in the constructor. And when you execute a function which gets a button like this as parameter, you can get the index of it e.g. with a function like this (put it in the inherited class): `int getIndex() { return buttonIndex; }`. And I assumed that you put these buttons with a code, not with Qt Designer.